# WPF VerticalAlignment="Top" is not working

Tags: wpf

I'm creating a table presentation out of WPF grid system. I can create the table though but my issue in the Merchandise portion is, as the `Non-Merchandise` grow taller, the data in `Merchandise` will vertically center even if I already set `VerticalAlignment="Top"`. The same issue with the `Tender` column. See the following image showing result.

```
<Grid Grid.Column="0" Grid.Row="1">
    <Grid.ColumnDefinitions>
        <ColumnDefinition Width="250" />
        <ColumnDefinition Width="250" />
        <ColumnDefinition Width="*" />
    </Grid.ColumnDefinitions>
    <Grid.RowDefinitions>
        <RowDefinition />
    </Grid.RowDefinitions>

    <Grid Grid.Column="0" Grid.Row="0" Background="Aqua">
        <Grid.ColumnDefinitions>
            <ColumnDefinition />
            <ColumnDefinition />
        </Grid.ColumnDefinitions>
        <Grid.RowDefinitions>
            <RowDefinition />
            <RowDefinition />
            <RowDefinition />
        </Grid.RowDefinitions>

        <TextBlock Text="Merchandise" Grid.Row="0" Grid.Column="0" Grid.ColumnSpan="2" HorizontalAlignment="Center" VerticalAlignment="Top" />
        <TextBlock Text="Amount" Grid.Row="1" Grid.Column="1" HorizontalAlignment="Right" Margin="5" />

        <TextBlock Text="Sales" Grid.Row="2" Grid.Column="0" VerticalAlignment="Top" />
        <TextBlock Text="25,887.22" Grid.Row="2" Grid.Column="1" HorizontalAlignment="Right" VerticalAlignment="Top" />

    </Grid>

    <Grid Grid.Column="1" Grid.Row="0" Background="Aquamarine">
        <Grid.ColumnDefinitions>
            <ColumnDefinition />
            <ColumnDefinition />
        </Grid.ColumnDefinitions>
        <Grid.RowDefinitions>
            <RowDefinition />
            <RowDefinition />
            <RowDefinition />
            <RowDefinition />
            <RowDefinition />
            <RowDefinition />
            <RowDefinition />
            <RowDefinition />
        </Grid.RowDefinitions>

        <TextBlock Text="Non-Merchandise" Grid.Row="0" Grid.Column="0" Grid.ColumnSpan="2" HorizontalAlignment="Center" />
        <TextBlock Text="Type" Grid.Row="1" Grid.Column="0" HorizontalAlignment="Left" Margin="5"/>
        <TextBlock Text="Amount" Grid.Row="1" Grid.Column="1" HorizontalAlignment="Right" Margin="5"/>

        <TextBlock Text="Gift Card" Grid.Row="2" Grid.Column="0" />
        <TextBlock Text="Gift Card" Grid.Row="3" Grid.Column="0" />
        <TextBlock Text="Gift Card" Grid.Row="4" Grid.Column="0" />
        <TextBlock Text="Gift Card" Grid.Row="5" Grid.Column="0" />
        <TextBlock Text="Gift Card" Grid.Row="6" Grid.Column="0" />
        <TextBlock Text="Gift Card" Grid.Row="7" Grid.Column="0" />
    </Grid>

    <Grid Grid.Column="2" Grid.Row="0" Background="AliceBlue">
        <Grid.ColumnDefinitions>
            <ColumnDefinition />
            <ColumnDefinition />
            <ColumnDefinition />
            <ColumnDefinition />
        </Grid.ColumnDefinitions>
        <Grid.RowDefinitions>
            <RowDefinition />
            <RowDefinition />
        </Grid.RowDefinitions>

        <TextBlock Text="Tender" Grid.Row="0" Grid.Column="0" Grid.ColumnSpan="4" HorizontalAlignment="Center" />
        <TextBlock Text="Description" Grid.Row="1" Grid.Column="0" HorizontalAlignment="Left" Margin="5"/>
        <TextBlock Text="Begin Amt" Grid.Row="1" Grid.Column="1" HorizontalAlignment="Right" Margin="5"/>
        <TextBlock Text="Trx Amt" Grid.Row="1" Grid.Column="2" HorizontalAlignment="Right" Margin="5"/>
        <TextBlock Text="Removed" Grid.Row="1" Grid.Column="3" HorizontalAlignment="Right" Margin="5"/>
    </Grid>

</Grid>
```

[image]

Answer (score 2, accepted):

A simple trick is to add an extra row at the bottom and set `Height="*"` while setting existing rows `Height="Auto"`. That way, existing rows will be pushed up to the top.

```xml
<Grid.RowDefinitions>
    <RowDefinition Height="Auto" />
    <RowDefinition Height="*" />
</Grid.RowDefinitions>
```

Comment: Oh yeah I forgot that asterisk... thanks man.